# how to limit the result for each category in laravel

Tags: sql, count, limit, laravel-5.8, rank

```
$user_info = DB::table('category_user')
                 ->select('user_id','category', DB::raw('count(*) as total'))
                 ->groupBy('user_id','category')
                 ->limit(3)
                 ->orderBy('total', 'desc')
                 ->get();
```

*the code that i write it will only display only 3 result from all the category*

i want to limit the result in top 3 for each category , for example there are 10 category and in each category has many data, i want to display only top 3 for each category.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this?

```
$user_info = DB::table('category_user')
                 ->select('user_id','category', DB::raw('count(*) as total'))
                 ->groupBy('user_id','category')->map(function($q){
                       return $q->take(3);
                   })->orderBy('total', 'desc')
                 ->get();
```